# Mirrored pose problem (IK goes crazy)

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I have a problem when I try to mirror my run animation, the IK bones on the foot go completely out of control on the mirrored portion of my animation.

The white keyframes are what I copied, and the yellow are the keyframes are the ones I pasted with (shift ctrl V)

[image]

[image]

The IK bones go completely out of control in the mirrored portion of the animation.

I used sebastian lague's amazing rigging video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI

Comment: Can you upload your blender file so we can have a better look for this issue.

Comment: Yes here it is sorry for the delay [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5324" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5324/)

Answer (score 3):

After take a look into your Blender's file. I think that your problem is about your *Leg Control* bones aren't have the same local rotation in edit mode. So whenever you do mirror paste, your bone will move at wrong direction.
How to fix it:

1. Select your armature then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*
2. Select both of your *Leg Control* bones then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and choose *Global + Z Axis*
   [image: Picture 1]
3. Back to *Pose Mode* and do your mirror paste, the rig is working perfectly now.
   [image]

P/S: You must re-animate your animation, because after reset rotation, your armature doesn't work correctly with current animation. Here is your file after i fix it. Sorry about my bad english, hope someone could edit this :(
[image]

Comment: You are a life saver thank you very much. and your English is just fine :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is just a coincidence. (I came here also from Sebastian's channel!)

The answer from Ryo is saved me, but I just want to make an update for some of like me. I use Blender 2.8 on macOS and shortcut here is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

Also the rig in original question is not the same as in tutorial.
So to make this work I had to recalculate roll for bones : Leg.L, Leg.R, Toe.L, Toe.R, LegIK.L and LegIK.R. Only after these steps it works.

[image]